# Understanding I/O blocking

Tags: java, linux

I have a binary linux executable which prints some bytes in stdout. I consume these bytes from Java application as this:

```
String[] cmd;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
int r = is.read();
while(r != -1){
    System.out.println(r);
    r = is.read(); //1
}
```

But after some time of working the `//1` is blocked for I/O forever (dead-lock). I created thread dump and noticed that

```
"pool-2-thread-1@627" prio=5 tid=0xd nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
      - locked <0x2c0> (a java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
```

It's locked on a native method

```
private native int readBytes(byte[] var1, int var2, int var3) throws IOException;
```

What's a possible reason this method is blocked forever? Maybe this is platform-specific. I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: Tell us more about the binary executable. If you run it on its own, does it run until you ctrl-C? Or does it return you to the command prompt?

Comment: @slim The binary exceutable is ran by just a command. Thats it. It reads data from a database and prints them in stdout.

Comment: Does it run until you ctrl-C? Or does it return you to the command prompt?

Comment: @slim untill command prompt

Comment: Isn't `InputStream#read()` blocking in nature of it is expected to be blocking  until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown? Read the documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read() .. I think it is expected behaviour

Comment: @hagrawal If it is dead-lock depends on the configuration in C code. So i guess it's platform specific. Maybe some buffer size

Comment: Worth noting that this is the exact behavior you would observe If the binary decided to display a prompt and sit there waiting for some input.

Comment: I don't think there is a dead-lock, IMHO it is a blocking nature, default buffer size is 8192 `private static int defaultBufferSize = 8192;`, I think your buffer is not getting filled.

Answer (score 2):

Your `InputStream` is waiting for the process to *either* supply another byte, or close the stream (by finishing).

One reason the process might be doing neither of those things, is that it's written to `stderr`, and is blocking on that write.

Possibly there is a difference in environment between your shell and the environment used by Java, that means the command is resulting in output to stderr (e.g. the program is not in `$PATH`; you don't have adequate permissions; your CWD isn't what you expect, etc.)

A quick and dirty way to find out if this is the problem, is to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` -- either with `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream()` or by using `2>&1` on the UNIX side of things.

*If* this is the case, then it *is* a form of deadlock -- the Java program is waiting for the native program to write to one pipe. The native program is waiting for the Java program to read from another.

The clean way to handle it, which you might choose to do in the longer term, is to use `getErrorStream()` and handle its output. This isn't exactly trivial, because in a single-threaded program using blocking reads, you can never know which stream is going to have data. You can either do blocking reads in separate threads, or use NIO to handle both inputs in a non-blocking manner.

By the way - note that the Java docs advise `ProcessBuilder.start()` over `Runtime.exec()`, since Java 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to look at the internal methods of the standard library for an answer.  [The docs of `InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) specify, in part, that

> If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data
>   is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is
>   thrown.

Perhaps the key point of confusion is the meaning of "the end of the stream is detected."  This *does not* mean that no more bytes are available to read right now -- that wouldn't be consistent with specification that the method blocks until data is available, and in practice it would work out poorly in many situations.  Rather, the end of the stream is detected when the system receives some sort of signal that no more bytes will *ever* be available from it.  Generally, that means that the stream has been closed on the source end, and all bytes drained from it at the destination end.

In your particular case, if the external process remains running, does not write anything further to its standard output, yet does not *close* its standard output, then Java (or a native consumer) will never see end-of-stream on that process's output.

Comment: Yes, but OP has said that when run at a prompt, the program writes some stuff then terminates. So we wouldn't expect it to (normally) hang around without closing the pipe.

Comment: @slim, it matters not what the OP claims the external process does when run directly from a command prompt.  If reading from its standard output blocks then that is because no bytes are available but the stream is still open on the source end.  When a process terminates, all its open file handles are closed, ergo it must not have terminated in the OP's case.  That is the answer to the OP's question.  Why that situation arises cannot be determined from the data provided.

Answer (score 1):

There are [five different type IO model](https://ethanhao.github.io/c,linux,io/2017/02/22/Five-different-types-IO-in-Linux.html) under Linux , they are respectively

- Blocking IO
- NonBlocking IO
- IO Multiplexing
- Signal-Driven
- Asynchornours IO

java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes() use first type, **Blocking IO**.  Application waits until kernel returns data.
[image]